# Angular 2 Material use lighter/darker colors on button

Tags: angular-material

Is there any elegant way to use lighter/darker variants of either primary or accent colors with buttons in angular 2 material without recreating whole styling by hand?

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdColors

Comment: At the moment, there is no such feature, although there is a submitted issue: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6059

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use sass you can import material theming into your scss file and target material colors like so:

**app.component.scss**

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

.buttonPrimary {
    background-color: mat-color($mat-purple, 200);
}

.buttonAccent {
    background-color: mat-color($mat-amber, A200);
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button md-raised-button class="buttonPrimary">primary</button>
<button md-raised-button class="buttonAccent">accent</button>
```

Comment: Thats how I ended up doing it, though for convienience I ended up with just lighter, darker classes that work for both primary and accent, and different types of buttons. But that's pretty much essence of what I did.