# Hues in Angular Material Theming

Tags: angular-material

When defining a palette, what is actually affected by the hues?

```
hpsapf-primary: mat-palette($mat-light-blue, 400, 50, 900);
```

- The first value (400) is the default hue.
- The second value (50) is the lighter hue.
- The third value (900) is the darker hue.

The default hue is used when setting color="primary" on a component

```
// The button gets the color #29B6F6 as can be looked up here: https://material.io/design/color/#tools-for-picking-colors
<button mat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
```

So how are the lighter (50) and darker (900) hues used by Angular Material or how can I use them? What are they good for?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you clarify your question?

Comment: default is 500. @function define-palette($base-palette, $default: 500, $lighter: 100, $darker: 700). https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/core/theming/_theming.scss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How they are used can be seen by looking at Angular Material source code. More specifically, look at some of the component theming mixin files. An example from [progress bar](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/9eeb4b5aa0473c0815a73bfe3c2ed6164d86a3b3/src/material/progress-bar/_progress-bar-theme.scss):

```
@mixin mat-progress-bar-theme($theme) {
  $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
  $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
  $warn: map-get($theme, warn);

  .mat-progress-bar-background {
    fill: mat-color($primary, lighter);
  }

  .mat-progress-bar-buffer {
    background-color: mat-color($primary, lighter);
  }

  .mat-progress-bar-fill::after {
    background-color: mat-color($primary);
  }
  ...
}
```

You can use them in the same manner through the theming utility mixins and functions and the default, lighter, darker, default-contrast, lighter-contrast, and darker-contrast palette map keys. It is explained in the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components#note-using-the-code-mat-color-code-function-to-extract-colors-from-a-palette.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
The first answer was somewhat right, the idea was there, I take my answers below back. It is a little vague, for someone new to angular-material, like me. The link below, or here [Angular 2 Material use lighter/darker colors on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118062/angular-2-material-use-lighter-darker-colors-on-button?rq=1) does answer what I need. The previous answer might work for a progress bar, but right now I do not see how it will work with buttons. If someone do know how, please do help out. Angular's docs are somewhat sparse. However I still prefer if I could use it like this

```
<button mat-button color="primary darker">Primary darker</button>
```

And maybe beside it I want the color to be default then I could use it like this

```
<button mat-button color="primary default">2nd default</button>
<button mat-button color="primary default">3rd default</button>
```

I guess that is how and what the question was all about.
UPDATE ENDS.

<strike>Since none of the answers here are anywhere but actually near. They seem to have missed the point. Some of us are a little picky with colors</strike>. So let me try to rephrase what the question is.

He simply wants to use something like this:

```
<button mat-button color="primary default">Primary default</button>
<button mat-button color="primary lighter">Primary lighter</button>
<button mat-button color="primary darker">Primary darker</button>
```

I hope that is what he wants to ask because it seems like it.

I think that answer might be found here [Angular 2 Material use lighter/darker colors on button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46118062/angular-2-material-use-lighter-darker-colors-on-button?rq=1)

IF that works that is the closest that I can think that might work. I will try it later and will edit this post in a bit.